# Trouble displaying tree structure

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to display a tree structure like this:

- Mission1

  - Activity1

    - Project1
  - Activity2
- Mission2

  - Activity3

    - Project2

But instead I'm getting a list that repeats the parent elements for every activity or project that is different like this:

- Mission1

  - Activity1

    - Project1
- Mission1

  - Activity2

I want to group the Activities and Projects under one parent ('Mission') element.

Here's my LINQ query:

```
var q = from mission in _context.tMissions
                join activity in _context.tActivities on mission.id equals activity.missionId
                join project in _context.tDefaultEventTypes on activity.id equals project.activityId
                where !project.isRemoved && project.defaultCategoryId == 4
                orderby mission.name
                select CreateFrom(project);

        return q.ToList();
```

I then just bind that to a list and display it on the page.  Here's my aspx:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlTierTypes" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# Eval("Activity.Mission.Name") %></li>
          <ul>
            <li><%# Eval("Activity.Name") %></li>
            <ul>
              <li><%# Eval("Name") %></li>
            </ul>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

And the code behind just binds it:

```
    public void SetTierTree(IEnumerable<DefaultEventType> tierList)
    {
      dlTierTypes.DataSource = tierList;
      dlTierTypes.DataBind();
    }
```

Not sure how to tackle this exactly.

EDIT - Here's my new function in the repository.

```
    public ICollection<DefaultEventType> GetTierTree()
    {
        var q = from mission in _context.tMissions
                join activity in _context.tActivities on mission.id equals activity.missionId
                join project in _context.tDefaultEventTypes on activity.id equals project.activityId
                where !project.isRemoved && project.defaultCategoryId == 4
                orderby mission.name
                select new DefaultEventType(project.tierLevel.TryParseEnum<GanttType>(GanttType.Unknown), DefaultCategoryRepository.CreateFrom(project.tDefaultCategory))
                {
                    //t = new DefaultEventType(project.tierLevel.TryParseEnum<GanttType>(GanttType.Unknown), DefaultCategoryRepository.CreateFrom(project.tDefaultCategory)),
                    AllowNumericSuffix = project.allowNumericSuffix,
                    AttachMilestoneMoniker = project.attachMilestoneMoniker,
                    Description = project.description,
                    Id = project.id,
                    IsReadOnly = project.isReadOnly,
                    IsSticky = project.isSticky,
                    Name = project.name,
                    Sid = project.sid,
                    Style = project.style.TryParseEnum<GanttElementStyle>(GanttElementStyle.Unknown),
                    TimeStamp = project.createdDT,
                    UpdatedTimeStamp = project.updatedDT,
                    Activity = new Activity { Id = activity.id, Name = activity.name, Mission = new Mission { Id = mission.id, Name = mission.name } }
                };

        var q2 = q.GroupBy(row => row.Activity.Mission.Id)
            .Select(group => group.GroupBy(row => row.Activity.Id));

        return q2.Cast<DefaultEventType>().ToList();
    }
```

But I receive this error when displaying the page:
'Could not convert from type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,DefaultEventType]]' to type 'DefaultEventType'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to adjust the query.  The use of `GroupBy` can *greatly* help in this example.

Just take exactly what you have, then group the results by mission.  The, for each group, group the missions by activity (this needs to be nested group bys, not sequential group bys).

```
var q2 = q.GroupBy(row => row.MissionID)
     .Select(group => group.GroupBy(row => row.ActivityID));
```

I'm not sure if your provider can do that mapping on the DB end or not; if not throw an `AsEnumerable` in that query where needed.

Next, you'll need to change how you render the data to reflect this change.

Rather than a single `DataList` you'll need 3 nested data lists.  You'll bind the whole query to the outer level which displays the mission, then subscribe to the data bound event to set the inner-group as the data source of that instance of the inner data list.  Then, in that inner data list, display the activity and bind the innermost group level to the innermost `DataList`, which can bind the project name normally.

Also, you may consider using a `TreeView` to render the data structure instead of a `DataList`, since a `TreeView` is designed to render trees.  I'm not sure if you needed to reject it for some reason or just didn't consider it, but it would probably be easier to work with.  If you do go that route the query will still be modified as I suggested, you just won't need any nested ASP controls.

Comment: The q2 variable throws this error in the results view when debugging: {"Method 'Project CreateFrom(Project)' has no supported translation to SQL."}  It also does not let me return q2.ToList().

Comment: @negzero7 I refer you to the section of my post discussing specifically that: `"I'm not sure if your provider can do that mapping on the DB end or not; if not throw an AsEnumerable in that query where needed."`  The "where needed" will almost certainly be just after all of what you had and just before the group bys.

Comment: Forgot to mention I added them:  var q2 = q.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Activity.Mission.Id)  
                .Select(group => group.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Activity.Id)).AsEnumerable();

Comment: @negzero7 Then the problem is with the first query, even without mine.  `CreateFrom` can't be converted to be on the database, so you need to take that out of `q`.  If you're just creating an object and assigning the properties it's probably best to just inline that code instead of using a method.  If it's doing more, I couldn't say what you should do without knowing what it does.